# How to return desired number in a 2d array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have problems with getting certain row or column number from an image data (barcode):
Say I have `image[row][col]`. How do I access row by a method?

```
public int getRow (Object[][] image){
    return image[row];
}
```

doesn't work.
Thank you.

Sorry for not figuring out correctly:
There's an image I have set to true and false, for example, `image[1][2] = true`, `image[1][3] = false` etc. Now, I need to print each and every image. When I try to do it by

```
for (row = 0; row < 1 (which is from image[1][]); row++){
    for (col = 0; col < 2 (which is from image[][2]; row++){
        System.out.print(image[row][col];
    }
}
```

Please let me know if additional info needed.

Comment: Ignoring that you don't seem to understand 2d arrays, how do you expect to return an `int` when you're passing in a 2d array of `Object` ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your image array contains integer values then you need to cast it to integer and return like this:

```
return (Integer)image[row][col];
```

where row,col you need to replace with the desired index.

Answer (score 1):

All `Bi-dimensional` arrays would work the same way, `ObjectType[Row][Column]`. This will `return` the `Object`  at the specified row and column. However, I believe (Could be wrong) that your posted programming statement is casting an `Image` to an `Object` array.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your actual problem statement. But in the above example you should **increase col** value instead of **row++**

It should be

```
for (col = 0; col < 2 ; col++){
    System.out.print(image[row][col]);
```

instead of

```
for (col = 0; col < 2 (which is from image[][2]; row++){
    System.out.print(image[row][col];
```